# How i can cancel a ExecuteReaderAsync with CancellationToken

Tags: c#, sql-server, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I have a long running query , when I try to abort the query with CancellationToken nothing happens.

```
using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = contrat.StoredProcedureName;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 2000;
    AddParameters(cmd, contrat.ParametresCommand);

    using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(Token))
    {
        return contrat.ConvertAsync(reader);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a timeout value on the token, or manually cancel the token.

Comment: I have already canceled my token  it's canceld in client side but it's not cancled in server side